# How to convert relative path to absolute path in dart?

Tags: dart, path

In nodejs I simply use path

```
import path from "path";
path.resolve(__dirname, '../', './test.txt');
```

Is there any way to use in dart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

void main(List<String> args) {
  final relative = 'example/example.dart';
  final absolute = path.normalize(path.absolute(relative));
  print(absolute);

  final dir = path.dirname(absolute);
  print(dir);
  final absolute2 =
      path.normalize(path.absolute(path.join(dir, '../', './test.txt')));
  print(absolute2);
}
```

Output (in my case):

```
E:\prj\dart_test\example\example.dart
E:\prj\dart_test\example
E:\prj\dart_test\test.txt
```

P.S.
I prefer to use `normalize` but this is matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `File.absolute.path`/`Directory.absolute.path`.